# How to put mat-expansion-header at the bottom of mat-expansion-content when expanded

Tags: angular-material

is it possible to put mat-expansion-header at the bottom of mat-expansion-content when expanded ?

I only have an arrow in the header, so I would like to have the arrow at the bottom of the panel when it is expanded.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to achieve the same. I moved the content that is displayed when the panel is collapsed above the panel. Then only displayed it when the panel is collapsed. Like so:

```
<p *ngIf="panelOpenState">I'm the panels content</p> 

<mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                     (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
      title
    </mat-panel-title>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

And in ts you need to have the panelOpenState variable:

`public panelOpenState = false;`

But in the end I replaced the whole mat-expansion-panel part with a button because I liked the look of it more..

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CSS only solution, at least on the latest version at the moment (v17.2.2) :

```
mat-expansion-panel { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/yuvxdk?file=src%2Fstyles.scss)